# SQL adjustable structure redundancy

Tags: sql, database, permissions, modularity

I have to build a database structure which allow a totally modular structure. Let's take an example, it will be easier to understand.

We have a website record, looking like this :

```
WEBSITE A 
| ----- SECTION A 
|          |-- SUBSECTION 1
|          |       | -- Data 1 : Value 1
|          |       | -- Data 2 : Value 2 
|          |       |     ...
|          |       | -- Data N : Value N 
|          |
|          |-- SUBSECTION 2 
|          |       | -- Data 52 : Value 1 
|          |       | -- Data 53 : Value 2 
|          |       |        ...
|          |       | -- Data M : Value M
|          |
|         ...
|
| ----- SECTION B 
|          |
|         ...
```

...

**Model 1 :**

And so on. The trouble is that I have to implement a permission system. For instance, User A have access to Section A,B,D,Z from website 1 whereas User 2 have acces to section C,V,W,X from website 2. 
First, I though that building this as a tree would be the most efficient way to do.
Here is my first database representation :

```
TABLE website (id, id_client, name, address)
TABLE section (id, id_website, name)
TABLE sub_section (id, id_section, name)
TABLE data (id, id_sub_section, key, value)
```

With this representation, it would be easy to give some restricted access to the employees.
However, both websites will have common data. For instance, all websites will have section A,B,C,D with the same structure. It implies a **lot of redundancy**. For each website, we'll have a lot of common structure, **the only difference will be the attribute value in the TABLE data**.

The second problem is that this structure have to be totally modular. For instance, the admin should be able to add a section, a subsection or a data to a website record. That's the reason why I though that this model is easier to manage.

**Model 2 :**

I have a second model, easier to store but harder to exploit :

```
TABLE website (id, id_client, Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 ... Value N)
TABLE section (id, name, Data 1, Data 2, Data 3 .. Data N, ..., Data 52, Data 53, Data M) (it represents the name of the columns)
TABLE subsection (id, id_section, name, Data 1, Data 2, Data N)
```

By doing this, I have a table where data are stored and "structural tables" with section and subsection in common with both websites. If the admin wants to add a section / subsection, we're going back to the tree structure to store additionnal data, looking like this :

```
TABLE additional_section (id,id_website,name)
TABLE additionnal_subsection (id,id_section, id_additional_section, name)
TABLE additional_data (id, id_subsection, id_additionnal_subsection, key, value)
```

It avoids a lot of redundancy and facilitate the permissions management.

**Here's my question :**

What's the best model for this kind of application ? Model 1 ? Model 2 ? Another one ? 
Thanks for reading and for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you modify Model 1.

You can eliminate the redundancy in the `section` table by removing the `id_website` FK from that table and create a new table between the `website` table and it.

This new table `WebsiteSection` has a PK that consist of an FK to `website` AND an FK to `section`, allowing each section to be part of multiple websites.

Section data that is common to all websites would then be stored in the `section` table while section data that is site specific would be stored in the `WebsiteSection` table.